# Serial voting on PPCG

Tags: support, voting

I was reading [What is serial voting and how does it affect me?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126829/what-is-serial-voting-and-how-does-it-affect-me) on meta stackexchange, and I realised that when browsing through the recent code-golf submissions (as I do a few times a week) I often go through the posts and upvote good answers. A few people ([Dennis](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/12012/dennis), [Martin Ender](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/8478/martin-ender), [Luis Mendo](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/36398/luis-mendo)) provides very good solutions, almost on a daily basis, causing me to upvote them 5-6 times within a 10-minute period regulary.

Will this cause any trouble for me or them, and do I risk that these votes gets blocked due to serial voting?

Comment: Incidentally: hey, thanks for that! :-)

Comment: The serial voting detection algorithm is not public, but I guess Dennis, Martin or Luis could let us know if they often get upvotes from rep reversed.

Comment: @trichoplax It has never happened to me AFAIK. Clearly, my answers are not good enough to trick the algorithm :-P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably not. 5-6 votes in 10 minutes usually isn't enough to be considered serial voting. Doing this over a long period of time might get the votes reversed, but you can always go back and re-vote (more slowly, with other votes interspersed) if it happens. The serial voting detection is usually smart enough to not trigger on someone upcoming a few users because they make good content that is worthy of upvotes.